# how to make a field of shakiness

Tags: animation, objects, add-on, animation-nodes, force-fields

Is there a way to make a 3d space of shakiness( or any kind of effect), that if an object passed by it or stay in it can be affected and when the object goes away of it that effect ends?

Thanks, guys :)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! What is "shakiness"? Can you please clarify your question.

Comment: Sure, Mr Omar, I mean by " Shakiness". " Shake to make the object which passes by this field move in many directions in a random way. Like when you shake your juice before drinking it :)

Comment: Look into force field objects in Blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an object "shake" using noise modifiers and drivers.

1. Create 3 objects. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
   [image]

   - A cube shaped empty named *Empty_ControlCube*. This object will be use to animate the movement of the cube.
   - A sphere shaped empty named *Empty_sphere*.
   - A cube. This object will be rendered.
2. Parent the latter two objects to the *Empty_ControlCube* <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. When you move the *Empty_ControlCube*, all three objects will move.
3. Add a "control field", in my case a circle. On and near this circle area, the cube should wiggle automatically.
4. Add a *Shrinkwrap* constraint to the *Empty_sphere*, choosing the *Circle* as the target. The *Empty_sphere* object will now clamp to the Circles area, even if you move the *Empty_ControlCube* away.
   [image]
5. Add a keyframe on the channels of the *Cube*, which you want to wiggle. Select the keyframe(s) in the graph editor and add a noise modifier. When you play/scrub you will see the noise added to the object. The next step is to make it not wiggle if it leaves the circle area. We'll do that by using the distance between the *Empty_sphere* and the *Empty_ControlCube* as the driver input.
   [image: asdf]
6. Add constraint to the cube, limiting the movement to `0`. Tick the boxes for the respective channels, where you added the noise animation. With limiting constraints active, you shouldn't see any movement anymore.
   [image]
7. Add a driver to the Influence of the constraints. Go to the drivers window and use the **distance** as an input variable. Choose the distance between *Empty_sphere* and *Empty_ControlCube*. Now the driver input (of the distance variable) will be `0` when the Cube and the *Empty_sphere* are at the same position. This is the case when the *Empty_ControlCube* is on the circle. Otherwise it will be larger than `0`. I added two keyframes to the driver graph to make the limit constraints active (influence is `1`) when the driver input (distance) is larger than 0. You can move the *Empty_ControlCube* and watch how the driver values change.
   [image: create]

[image: result]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The *[Wiggle Falloff](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/falloff/wiggle_falloff.html)* node can be used to introduced the wiggling. The output falloff can then be multiplied with a *Point Distance Falloff* or an *[Object Controller Falloff](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/falloff/object_controller_falloff.html)* to limit the wiggling to a certain field only:

[image: Node Tree]